# Setting default browser for zathura

Tags: chrome, xdg-open, zathura

So I have trouble setting the default browser for opening links in zathura.
I would like to use chrome however Palemoon is always used instead.

I am on Manjaro with i3.

First of all `xdg-open "https://www.google.com"` uses chrome properly. When I open any link in zahura following errors are thrown in the terminal:

```
[1:1:1106/105839.089082:ERROR:nacl_fork_delegate_linux.cc(329)] Bad NaCl helper startup ack (0 bytes)
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 756: 26008 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) "$command_exec" "$@"
```

And Palemoon opens the link. Is it because it was set as default browser in `.profile`?

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like Zathura run `xdg-open` which starts Chrome but it crashes.

Answer (score 7):

In your ~/.config/zathura/zathurarc, add a the line

`set sandbox none`

Follow the issue [here](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/-/issues/151).

Comment: Thanks, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

For me, having `xdg-open some-url` open a broweser is not enough for zathrura to follow the links. I also had to `xdg-settings set default-web-browser my-browser.desktop`.

---

I normally use [qutebrowser](https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/) instead of Chrome, and I had never cared about what `xdg-open some-url` does, until I bumped into this question because of zathura not opening the URLs.

So I tried what `xdg-open "https://www.google.com"` did, and it was indeed opening a browser (despite the wrong one, Chrome), but zathura wouldn't follow the links anyway.

Therefore I tried setting the correct browser first:

```bsh
xdg-settings set default-web-browser org.qutebrowser.qutebrowser.desktop
```

and then zathura behaved correctly.